# Finding the network equivalent impedance Z(t)

Tags: impedance

I am a bit lost no how to approach this problem? What should I do to get the total impedance?

[image: The question]

Comment: Do you know how to find the impedance of each element? Do you know how to combine impedance in series and in parallel?

Comment: Would you have the same problem if these were resistors?

Comment: In case you want to make your own filter on the fly or from CIrcuits menu But this sweep is too fast to get the actual Q of 10,000 for this 32kHZ resonator 

http://www.falstad.com/afilter/

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5wkh.png

Answer (score 1):

Combine L and C2 with a parallel equation, and combine R and C1 with a series equation.

The frequency impedance of each component is in these equations.

[image]
Source: https://circuit2.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/impedance-and-admittance/

Answer (score 0):

While Voltage Spike's answer is correct, it might be a little hard for a newbie to understand.
The key to unlocking it is converting from angular frequency(aka radians/second)(ω) to a form more easily entered into a calculator(2πf), where f is frequency in Hertz.
Afterwards you have XL = 2πfL(where L is inductance in Henrys) and XC = 1/2πfC(where C is capacitance in Farads)

You are also missing a key part for your question, the frequency. Capacitive and inductive impedance are both frequency dependent.

Once your have solved for your reactive impedance(which is measured in Ohms) you would then calculate the total as if everything was a resistor.

I'm going to solve for this example circuit, at 1KHz:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7PUQX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Solve for reactive impedance first:

XL1(44uH) = 2 * 3.14 * 1000 * 0.000044   = .276 Ohms
XC1(1uF)  = 1/(2 * 3.14 * 1000 * .00001) = 159 Ohms
XC2(1uF)  = 1/(2 * 3.14 * 1000 * .00001) = 159 Ohms

Next solve the parallel impedance:
XL1 * XC1 / XL1 + XC1 = .276 * 159 / .276 + 159 = 43.884 / 159.276 = .276 Ohms

Now add it all together:
NOTE: Resistance is not frequency dependent.
 50 + .276 + 100 + 159 = 309.276 Ohms
So at 1Khz the circuit has an impedance of 309.276 Ohms